# How to set static IP address for Wi-Fi connection on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, phone, static-ip

We need to set a static IP address (and DNS etc.) to connect to our workplace Wi-Fi, but I couldn't find an option on my bq Aquaris E5 device. How should I do it?

Comment: There is a year old feature request to implement this setting http://pad.lv/1445772, but sadly not much activity. I'm here asking for a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried setting a custom network interface in terminal?
http://snipplr.com/view/1737/

Comment: @mikeymop I edited the network profile in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-settings/` and it worked for me

Comment: @mikeymop: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: If you run do a $less /etc/NetworkManager/system-settings > ~/networkSettings.txt and upload the file it leaves in your home folder I can better tailor my answer for you.

Comment: @Fabby: let me know if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you can modify

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-settings
```

A quick Google search reveals [this guide](http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/09/08/static-ip-wifi-network-ubuntu-touch/)

With a text editor. This is in XML format, if you're unfamiliar don't be afraid. Skim through the whole thing, it's like a settings screen.

You need to determine which device is represented by your WiFi adapter.

```
ip addr show wlan0
```

Find your wifi connection information

```
ip route show
```

Look for the connection that is related to wlan0, this will show you both the SSID (wifi name) and the ip address assigned to the phone.

Get your DNS

```
getprop net.dns1
```

Keep all of this information handy as you'll need to write a configuration file.

Open terminal on your device as a superuser.

```
#cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
#ls
# cat [name of wireless device wlan0]
```

This will list the formatting of the automatic wireless configuration that will made when you connected to your wifi network, use this as a base to make you static ip address assignment.

```
$sudo apt-get install vim
$sudo vim [name of wireless device wlan0]
```

Look in this file for the header that says `[ipv6]`,hit 'i' to switch to insert mode, and change the line below it to show `method=ignore`

Move on to the header for `[ipv4]` and make the following changes:

```
[ipv4]
method=manual
address1=[staticIP/netmask],[default ip route]
dns=8.8.8.8;[your ISP's DNS address];
```

You can save these changes by hitting escape and typing `:wq`

Turn off wifi and turn it back on.

Comment: You should suggest a different text editor than vim. You also didn't specify how to get vim into insert mode. Just change it to something like nano.

Comment: As promised!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Once you boot into Ubuntu Touch, connect to the chosen Wi-Fi network.
Then, drop to the shell prompt.

```
adb shell
```

Then check the current IP address of your device and verify if it's
the same IP as Android. If not, then follow the steps below.

```
root@ubuntu-phablet:~# ip addr show wlan0
```

Navigate to the NetworkManager folder and look for the Wi-Fi SSID name

```
 cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
 ls
 cat YOURWIFINAME
```

**Your wifi connection should look like this:**

```
[connection] id=YOURWIFINAME uuid=WIRELESS-UUID type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WIFISSID mode=infrastructure
mac-address=WIRELESS:CARD:MAC:ADDRESS [ipv6] method=auto [ipv4]
method=auto
```

To change to static IP and ignore IPV6 address, you will
need to change the sections in [ipv6] and [ipv4]. The changes to be
made are shown in the file below in bold,italics. Use the `vi` editor to
edit the file (don’t use up and down arrow keys in edit mode). Nano,
which is the default editor in Ubuntu Touch,did not allow me to save
the file due to some reason.

```
 vi YOURWIFINAME
```

> [connection] id=YOURWIFINAME uuid=WIRELESS-UUID type=802-11-wireless [802-11-wireless] ssid=WIFISSID
>   mode=infrastructure mac-address=WIRELESS:CARD:MAC:ADDRESS [ipv6]
>   method=ignore [ipv4] method=manual
>   address1=your.device.ip.address/netmask,your.default.ip.route
>   `#` The following is Google's DNS, works everywhere.
>   dns=8.8.8.8
>   `#` or use your DNS IP address

Save the file. Disconnect and reconnect the Wi-Fi from the Ubuntu Touch UI to get the static IP going. You can verify the ip using the command:

```
ip addr show wlan0
```

## Enjoy!

[Source](http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/09/08/static-ip-wifi-network-ubuntu-touch/)

Comment: edited *and* upvoted!