# Unable to use static IP on Ubuntu Touch (current stable release)

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-touch, static-ip

I don't know why I can connect to the LAN but not to external servers.

I've configured Touch according to this post, but still can't connect to anything else than the router itself (192.168.1.1).

[How to set static IP address for Wi-Fi connection on Ubuntu phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751239/how-to-set-static-ip-address-for-wi-fi-connection-on-ubuntu-phone/759497#759497)

I've also tried to connect to servers usings their IPs instead of their URLs, to check whether the problem it's just about resolving IPs, with the DNSs, but I can't, whatever I do, I can only connect to the router.

Network config file:

> [...]
>
> [ipv4]
>
> method=manual
>
> address1=192.168.1.198/24,192.168.1.1
>
> dns=62.36.225.150;62.37.228.20;8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
>
> [ipv6]
>
> [...]
>
> method=ignore
>
> [...]

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a default gateway set up?

Comment: Where? Regarding to default gateway, the only thing I've tried is switching the above 192.168.1.254 with 192.168.1.1, but still not working